# How to add a static block above top link area in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I want to add a CMS static block above **top links** section.

Comment: You can do it the same way as in the linked duplicate, but use "Page Top" instead of "Page Header"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a static block anywhere you want. Use this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('blockidentifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: You mean i have to call this in top.links.phtml file

Comment: I mean anywhere you want. Where ever you want to show that block if its inside a .phtml file you can call it.

Comment: Thank you this worked ,actually i am adding it to top.links.phtml. But Now i added to header.phtml above all html. Thank You Sir !

Answer (score 2):

Put below code in your theme's `local.xml` file

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="cms/block" name="Promo" before="top.links">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>yourCMSBlockIdentifier</block_id></action>
        </block> 
    </reference>
</default>
```

**EDIT**

Or go to `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml`

and find `$this->getChildHtml('topLinks')` this code and before that

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('yourCMSBlockIdentifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

write above code

Comment: I already tried this Sir .But it dosn`t work.

Comment: the block isn't call or it calls some other place ??

Comment: This Block isn't called anywhere. I checked the content of block in page source also but no content is rendering.

Comment: May be that layout is not getting called please try with some other layout file

Comment: Thank You @Murtuza Sir , You always replied whenever i raised a question . Thank you so much.

Comment: You are always welcome bro :)